# Split Data by Ignoring Semicolon Inside Square Bracket in Python

Tags: python, split

I want to split the data by Semi Colon, But i need to ignore the semi colon inside the Square Bracket.

```
val = "L=1nH;Tol=0.3nH;Idc=1000mA;Isat=NA;Iacpp=NA;Fr=10GHz;ESR=0.10ohm;Q=[100MegHz 7; 500MegHz 23;1.8GHz 47;2.4GHz 57];dL@Isat=NA;dT@Idc=NA"
val.split(";")
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.findall` we can try:

```py
val = "L=1nH;Tol=0.3nH;Idc=1000mA;Isat=NA;Iacpp=NA;Fr=10GHz;ESR=0.10ohm;Q=[100MegHz 7; 500MegHz 23;1.8GHz 47;2.4GHz 57];dL@Isat=NA;dT@Idc=NA"
parts = re.findall(r'\w+=\[.*?\]|\w+=[^;]+', val)
print(parts)
```

The regex pattern used here says to match:

```regex
\w+=\[.*?\]  a key = a term in [...]
|            OR
\w+=[^;]+    a key = some other term
```

The regex alternation places the `key=[...]` variant first, so that we avoid trying to match to semicolons internal to the bracketed value.

Comment: That’s cool! Would you mind explaining how goes the logic inside `findall`?

Comment: @mgmussi Check my updated answer.  The regex alternation does an eager find on the key=[...] variant.  Only if that fails, does it use semicolon to find the end of the value.

Answer (score 0):

You could split on capturing the data from an opening till closing square bracket in a capture group to keep it in the output,  or split on  `;` using an alternation `|` in the pattern.

```
([^\s=;]+=\[[^][]*])|;
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1** (keep after split)

  - `[^\s=;]+=` Match 1+ chars other than a whitespace char `;` or `=` and then match `=`
  - `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]`
- `)` Close group 1
- `|` Or
- `;` Match a semicolon

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/DYa6lf/1).

Example

```
import re

val = "L=1nH;Tol=0.3nH;Idc=1000mA;Isat=NA;Iacpp=NA;Fr=10GHz;ESR=0.10ohm;Q=[100MegHz 7; 500MegHz 23;1.8GHz 47;2.4GHz 57];dL@Isat=NA;dT@Idc=NA"
pattern = r"([^\s=;]+=\[[^][]*])|;"
result = [s for s in  re.split(pattern, val) if s]
print(result)
```

Output

```
['L=1nH', 'Tol=0.3nH', 'Idc=1000mA', 'Isat=NA', 'Iacpp=NA', 'Fr=10GHz', 'ESR=0.10ohm', 'Q=[100MegHz 7; 500MegHz 23;1.8GHz 47;2.4GHz 57]', 'dL@Isat=NA', 'dT@Idc=NA']
```

---

A matching approach instead of split:

```
[^\s;=]+=(?:\[[^][]*]|[^;]+)
```

This pattern matches:

- `[^\s;=]+` Match 1+ char other than `;` `=` or a whitespace char
- `=` Match literally
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\[[^][]*]` Match from `[...]`
  - `|` Or
  - `[^;]+` Match any char except `;`
- `)` Close non capture group

See the regex matches at this [rexex 101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/NyZXd6/1).

Comment: @KellyBundy You are right, thanks for the sharp observation :-) I have updated the answer to match the part before and including the equals sign.

Comment: Yes, looks like it works, though at this point it rather looks like *matching* that value, and feels odd to use `split` that way. So I like Tim's way better. Splitting at `r";(?![^[]*\])"` [might be alright](https://tio.run/##NY9dC4IwFIbv9yvWrjRCZioGh1FdVAol9HFnBiNHCX6MuYL88zYpr84D78M555Uf/WxqbyFV3xeVbJTGSiD05iVmmOyZW0dwaUpGHc9QnN@ZSymt1hC3XLPETH6XcoCtMtEu6mBzPhndpc2zgiNLjX8Qj6jDIeBg5LkHrrMwNvZDmDv@QEGYQb5fjYvzy2o4l6wJklxroWrzkSJgLSfpLc2m18wmSIn2VeohEE4ry0Jbf3eGTQUbSVXU2vpZdt9/AQ). Do you see a better way to really implement "split at semicolon except inside []"?

Comment: @KellyBundy That might get unexpected results when there is only a single `]` to the right https://regex101.com/r/W4q5AN/1 But if the data is always with an opening and closing square bracket it could be a possibility